# Can't call an output-id multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a simple "calculator" that outputs me an XML-compatible table that I can copy+paste somewhere else.

I know nothing about JavaScript and so far I copied+pasted things together, changing it to my needs; I know very, very basic HTML but I can't seem to find the issue.

In this form, I have two inputs and they are used in quite a few variables, however I need the results to be used multiple times. When I try to get the same output a 2nd time though, it just gives no result. If I delete the first result, it works at the 2nd position. Is this intended, and how can I get the same result a 2nd time?

Here's my code, it's still very rudimental because I'm in the phase of building the basics

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<style>
#editor { white-space:pre; }  
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        function rechne() {
            var nenndurchmesser = document.getElementById('nenndurchmesser'),
                steigung = document.getElementById('steigung');

            var majordiaEXT = nenndurchmesser.valueAsNumber - 0.092;
            var pitchdiaEXT = nenndurchmesser.valueAsNumber - 0.568;
            var minordiaEXT = nenndurchmesser.valueAsNumber - 1.0155;

            var majordiaINT = nenndurchmesser.valueAsNumber + 0.214;
            var pitchdiaINT = nenndurchmesser.valueAsNumber - 0.407;
            var minordiaINT = nenndurchmesser.valueAsNumber - 0.717;
            var tapdrill = nenndurchmesser.valueAsNumber - steigung.valueAsNumber;

            document.getElementById('nenndurchmesser_res')
                .value = nenndurchmesser.valueAsNumber;
            document.getElementById('steigung_res')
                .value = steigung.valueAsNumber; 

            document.getElementById('majordiaEXT_res')
                .value = majordiaEXT;
            document.getElementById('pitchdiaEXT_res')
                .value = pitchdiaEXT; 
            document.getElementById('minordiaEXT_res')
                .value = minordiaEXT;                

            document.getElementById('majordiaINT_res')
                .value = majordiaINT;
            document.getElementById('pitchdiaINT_res')
                .value = pitchdiaINT; 
            document.getElementById('minordiaINT_res')
                .value = minordiaINT;                
            document.getElementById('tapdrill_res')
                .value = tapdrill;
            }
        document.getElementById("Gewindeangaben")
            .addEventListener("input", rechne);
    });
    </script>
<form id="Gewindeangaben">
    <legend>metrisches Gewinde</legend>
  
    <label for="nenndurchmesser">M</label>
    <input type="number" min="25" max ="122" placeholder="Nenndurchmesser" id="nenndurchmesser" value="0" step="1">

    <label for="steigung">x</label>
    <input type="number" min="0.75" max ="1.00" placeholder="Steigung" id="steigung" value="0.75" step="0.25">

  <br></form><br>
Gewinde M<output id="nenndurchmesser_res"></output>x<output id="steigung_res"></output><br>
<br>

        <!-- this List works -->
externe Gewinde<br>
MajorDia: <output id="majordiaEXT_res"></output><br>
PitchDia: <output id="pitchdiaEXT_res"></output><br>
MinorDia: <output id="minordiaEXT_res"></output><br>
<br>
interne Gewinde<br>
MajorDia: <output id="majordiaINT_res"></output><br>
PitchDia: <output id="pitchdiaINT_res"></output><br>
MinorDia: <output id="minordiaINT_res"></output><br>
Tapdrill: <output id="tapdrill_res"></output><br>


        <!-- the same output variables don't work a 2nd time -->
<p id="editor">
    <code>
&lt;ThreadSize&gt; 
    &lt;Size&gt;<output id="nenndurchmesser_res">0</output>.0&lt;/Size&gt; 
    &lt;Designation&gt; 
    &lt;ThreadDesignation&gt;M<output id="nenndurchmesser_res">0</output>x<output id="steigung_res">0</output>&lt;/ThreadDesignation&gt;
    &lt;CTD&gt;M<output id="nenndurchmesser_res">0</output>x<output id="steigung_res">0</output>&lt;/CTD&gt;
        &lt;Pitch&gt;<output id="steigung_res">0</output>&lt;/Pitch&gt;
        &lt;Thread&gt;
            &lt;Gender&gt;external&lt;/Gender&gt;
            &lt;Class&gt;6g&lt;/Class&gt;
            &lt;MajorDia&gt;<output id="majordiaEXT_res">0</output>&lt;/MajorDia&gt;
            &lt;PitchDia&gt;<output id="pitchdiaEXT_res">0</output>&lt;/PitchDia&gt;
            &lt;MinorDia&gt;<output id="minordiaEXT_res">0</output>&lt;/MinorDia&gt;
      &lt;/Thread&gt;
      &lt;Thread&gt;
            &lt;Gender&gt;internal&lt;/Gender&gt;
            &lt;Class&gt;6H&lt;/Class&gt;
            &lt;MajorDia&gt;<output id="majordiaINT_res">0</output>&lt;/MajorDia&gt;
            &lt;PitchDia&gt;<output id="pitchdiaINT_res">0</output>&lt;/PitchDia&gt;
            &lt;MinorDia&gt;<output id="minordiaINT_res">0</output>&lt;/MinorDia&gt;
            &lt;TapDrill&gt;<output id="tapdrill_res">0</output>&lt;/TapDrill&gt;
      &lt;/Thread&gt;
    &lt;/Designation&gt;
&lt;/ThreadSize&gt;
</code>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```js
const 
  Gform = document.forms['Gewindeangaben']
, cEdit = document.getElementById('c_edit')
, infos = 
  { majordiaEXT: { nam1: 'nenndurchmesser', val: 0, add : -0.092  }
  , pitchdiaEXT: { nam1: 'nenndurchmesser', val: 0, add : -0.568  }
  , minordiaEXT: { nam1: 'nenndurchmesser', val: 0, add : -1.0155 }
  , majordiaINT: { nam1: 'nenndurchmesser', val: 0, add : +0.214  }
  , pitchdiaINT: { nam1: 'nenndurchmesser', val: 0, add : -0.407  }
  , minordiaINT: { nam1: 'nenndurchmesser', val: 0, add : -0.717  }
  , tapdrill:  { nam1: 'nenndurchmesser', nam2: 'steigung', nam2_op: '-', val: 0  }
  }
, cEdit_Show = () =>
  {
  cEdit.textContent =
`  <ThreadSize> 
    <Size>0.0</Size> 
    <Designation> 
    <ThreadDesignation>M0x0</ThreadDesignation>
    <CTD>M0x0</CTD>
    <Pitch>0</Pitch>
    <Thread>
      <Gender>external</Gender>
      <Class>6g</Class>
      <MajorDia>${infos.majordiaEXT.val}</MajorDia>
      <PitchDia>${infos.pitchdiaEXT.val}</PitchDia>
      <MinorDia>${infos.minordiaEXT.val}</MinorDia>
    </Thread>
      <Thread>
        <Gender>internal</Gender>
        <Class>6H</Class>
        <MajorDia>${infos.majordiaINT.val}</MajorDia>
        <PitchDia>${infos.pitchdiaINT.val}</PitchDia>
        <MinorDia>${infos.minordiaINT.val}</MinorDia>
        <TapDrill>${infos.tapdrill.val}</TapDrill>
      </Thread>
    </Designation>
  </ThreadSize>`
  }

cEdit_Show()
Gform.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault()
Gform.oninput = () =>
  {
  Object.keys(infos).forEach( key =>
    {
    let ik = infos[key]
    if (!ik.nam2) ik.val = Gform[ik.nam1].valueAsNumber + ik.add
    else          ik.val = Gform[ik.nam1].valueAsNumber - Gform[ik.nam2].valueAsNumber
    })
  cEdit_Show()
  }
```

```css
form {
  font-family : 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  }
form fieldset { 
  margin-top : 1em;
  width      : 32em;
  }
form legend { 
  font-style : oblique;
  padding    : 0 1em;
  }
form label { 
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  margin  : .3em .4em;
  }
form label span { 
  font-size     : .9em;
  padding-right : .2em;
  }
form label input { 
  display : block;
  clear   : left;
  }
pre {
  width   : 39em;
  padding : .3em;
  border  : 1px solid grey;
  color   : darkblue;
  }
```

```html
<form name="Gewindeangaben">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>metrisches Gewinde</legend>
    <label>
      <span>Nenndurchmesser</span>
      <input name="nenndurchmesser" type="number" min="25" max ="122" value="0" step="1">
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Steigung</span>
      <input name="steigung" type="number" min="0.75" max ="1.00" value="0.75" step="0.25">
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
 
<pre id="c_edit" contenteditable spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" ></pre>
```